# Copy text from closest element into a field with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a series of products that get output with markup like this:

```
<div class="product">
    <p class="title">Product 01</p>
    <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <p class="title">Product 02</p>
    <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <p class="title">Product 03</p>
    <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>
```

...and a single form on the same page with an H3 and this hidden field...

```
<form>
    <h3></h3>
    <input type="hidden" id="help" name="help" value="" />
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is, if for example, you click on 'Enquire' for any of the products, the product title gets copied to the form in the H3 tag and also into the 'help' hidden field value.

I tried doing this but it didn't quite work as expected:

```
$('.enquire').click(function() {
    $('form h3').text($('.title').text());
    $('form #help').val($('.title').text());
});
```

Anu help would be awse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because your logic is selecting the text from *all* the `.title` elements. You instead need to traverse the DOM to read the text of the `.title` relevant to the `.enquire` which was clicked. To do that you could use `siblings()`, like this:

```js
$('.enquire').click(function() {
  var title = $(this).siblings('.title').text();
  $('form h3').text(title);
  $('form #help').val(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <p class="title">Product 01</p>
  <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p class="title">Product 02</p>
  <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p class="title">Product 03</p>
  <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>
<form>
  <h3></h3>
  <input type="text" id="help" name="help" value="" />
</form>
```

Note that I changed the hidden field to be visible for this demonstration, the logic is otherwise identical.

Comment: How does line two of your JS work? If I'm reading that correctly, you're setting a variable to be the siblings of the`.title` which doesn't make sense to me (because what are the siblings of `.title`?). Or is 'siblings' just a jQuery misnomer? That said, your solution works, so thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) As the DOM is a tree structure each element, or node, has a parent, and optionally, children and siblings. Siblings are other nodes which share the same parent element. As such jQuery's `siblings()` method will look for other elements at the same level as the current one which match the selector you provide.

Comment: Props for the excellent explanation. If I could upvote you again I would.

Answer (score 1):

Worked with this jquery:

```
$('.enquire').click(function() {
    $('#test h3').text($(this).parent().children().first().text());
    $('#test #help').val($(this).parent().children().first().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read the text of sibling `p` tag by using `prev()` function something like this:

```
$('.enquire').click(function() {
    var productName=$(this).prev("p").text()
    $('form h3').text(productName);
    $('form #help').val(productName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click function doesn't know which `.title` is using, so you need to get the target from click:

```
$('.enquire').click(function(e) {
    //var title = $(e.target).closest('.product').find('.title').text();
    // or
    var title = $(e.target).prev('.title').text();
    $('form h3').text(title);
    $('form #help').val(title);
});
```

Comment: Instead of `e.target`, you can just use `this`. It will point to the clicked `.enquire`, which is the correct target.

Answer (score 0):

Your code concatenate all the `.title`  elements text values - just get the one contained in the clicked element's `parent`:

```js
$(".enquire").click(function() {
  $("form h3").text($(this).parent().find("p").text());
  $("form input").val($(this).parent().find("p").text());
  console.log($("form input").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <p class="title">Product 01</p>
  <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <p class="title">Product 02</p>
  <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <p class="title">Product 03</p>
  <span class="enquire">Enquire</span>
</div>

<form>
  <h3></h3>
  <input type="hidden" id="help" name="help" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: Whoops @RoryMcCrossan, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is store the title text into a variable. You also need to use `this` since you have n products. Hope it helps

```
$('.enquire').on('click', function() {
        var thisTitle = $(this).prev().text();
        console.log(thisTitle);
        $('form h3').text(thisTitle);
        $('form #help').val(thisTitle);
});
```